# Limits with assumptions

Tags: assumptions

I have an example where Mathematica is not able to compute limits in a function restricted to assume that the input parameter is Real. I don't understand why this is so.
1. Could someone explain why this is a problem?
2. Is there a way to get around it, other than removing the restrictions on my function?

I would appreciate any help.

---

Here's the code:

```
blah3[x_] := -(1/32) x^4 Log[x^2/E^5.4076];
blah4[x_ /; x \[Element] Reals] := -(1/
    32) x^4 Log[x^2/E^5.4076];
Limit[-(1/32) x^4 Log[x^2/^E^5.4076], x -> 0]
Limit[blah3[Sin[x]], x -> 0]
Limit[blah4[Sin[x]], x -> 0]
```

The first two work, while the third limit evaluation does not.

---

Here's the context for the problem:

I'm trying to compare 
$$\int_0^\infty x^2 Log[1-E^{-\sqrt{\xi^2+x^2}}]$$
with its Taylor expansion, where the first few terms are given by $$-\frac{\pi ^4}{45}+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta ^2}{12}-\frac{\pi  \zeta ^3}{6}-\frac{1}{32} \zeta ^4 \log \left(\frac{\zeta ^2}{a_b}\right) + \ldots$$

To do this, I'm evaluating the former numerically and comparing against the latter approximation (of which `blah3` and `blah4` capture the part that is not easily calculable near $\xi = 0$). Just to ensure that I don't blindly trust results where things could go wrong (eg: $\xi^2 < 0$) I put in a condition that $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ in my function definitions.

Comment: Seems, this is because everything is maintained in a symbolic form when calculating the limit. As functions such as `Sin[x]` are not something with head `Real`, the rule `blah4[...] -> -(1/32)...` does not apply. In fact even `blah3[x]` returns -1/32 x^4 Log[0.0048259 x^2] whereas `blah4[x]` stays unevaluated unless x is a variable with a specific *real* value.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain the purpose of having the restrictions on your function, I could come up with an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A conditional definition (using `/;`, that is) is not the same thing as a "`Limit` with assumptions", so far as Mathematica is concerned. To achieve that one does e.g. `Limit[...,Assumptions->...]`. To un derstand why, notice that, as written, `blah4[Sin[x]]` does not evaluate. So `Limit` can do nothing with it.

For your example, below is a form that Mathematica will be able to work with.

```
Limit[blah3[Sin[x]], x -> 0, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```